# Can we setup a recurring function that executes every 5mins?

Tags: optimization

We want to track how our internal team is using our addon. Can I setup a function that reads the current active file that is open and log the time along with it, every 5minutes.

Comment: You can get the full path with `py.data.filepath`  or just the filename with `bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)`. I think you can use standard Python timers to get the timing and then standard Python file handles to log the data.

Comment: Use modal time operator. Follow the accepted answer - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120173/21121